# Cerrar una hoja de calculo de google despues de ejecutar un Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

A ver si me podeis echar una mano. Tengo una hoja de calculo de google y me gustaria que despues de rellenar unos datos, el ejecutar un script se cerrase automaticamente.

¿Sabeis como sería posible hacerlo? He estado investigando y no encuentro nada.

Un saludo y gracias
Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible.

Lo anterior es debido a que Google Apps Script no puede acceder al navegador ni su entorno entiendase computadora, sistema operativo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, crea un botón que tenga asignado el siguiente script

````
 var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 hoja.setActiveSheet(hoja.getSheetByName('Sección 1'),true);
 hoja.getSheetByName('Sección 1').showSheet();
 hoja.getSheetByName('Hola').hideSheet(); ## Esta linea oculta la hoja 
} ```
````